# Visual Studio Express 2013 errors for VC++ Win32 project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I installed VS Express 2013. I have no internet. So got two warnings after install - 1)We could not verify/validate certificates and 2) You are not using Internet Explorer 10. Both warnings indicated there could be problems as a result.

I start a VC++ Win32 proj and try and build and get 1 error and 38 warnings, all the warnings expect one are about intellisense not recognizing identifiers etc.

Any idea whats going on here? On Win 7 Sp1.

Win32 application VS2013
Warning 1   warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.   D:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets 355 5   Win32Project2

Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDKDDKVer.h': No such file or directory d:\users\and\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\win32project2\win32project2\targetver.h  8   1   Win32Project2

```
4   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "windows.h"   d:\Users\and\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project2\Win32Project2\stdafx.h 12  1   Win32Project2


5   IntelliSense: identifier "HINSTANCE" is undefined   d:\Users\and\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project2\Win32Project2\Win32Project2.cpp    10  1   Win32Project2

4   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "windows.h"   d:\Users\and\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\stdafx.h 12  1   Win32Project3
```

Comment: This looks like an incomplete install - you are missing parts of the Windows SDK for VS2013, maybe this is because you have no internet and the installer downloads it on demand.

Comment: Maybe, I take it the latest Windows SDK 8.1 is installed with VS2013, is there any way I can download a WSDK8.1 ISO(redistributable etc) - can't see anything on google?

Comment: So, you didn't [find this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/bg162891.aspx)? Can't you install online?

Comment: Can't use that, it seems there is no ISO. This is a paths problem. I tried to add the environ paths to windows SDk/v 7.1A etc but didn't work, maybe uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Anyone else, should WindowsSDKDir point at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs or C:\Program Files\Windows Kits, what is difference between these? I have changed both the registry and environ paths but VS still not linked.

Comment: Are there windows.h and sdkddkver.h on your hard drive?

Comment: To confirm did you install *Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop* or *Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows*?